# Repeating Images HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am a little confused on how to get a repeating image with html and css. Here I have this code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="top_background"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and then in style.css:

```
/* Reset CSS */

html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, img, ul, li, fieldset, form, label { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0; font-size: 100%; vertical-align: baseline; background: transparent; }

ol, ul { list-style: none; }

:focus { outline: 0; }

/* Content */

#top_background { background: url(images/header.png) repeat-x; }
```

But when I load the file it's just a blank web page. Taking out the 'repeat-x' doesn't change anything. I am fairly new to html and css, so I could be doing something completely wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the path to your image is wrong.

Comment: Dear see my answer and try to implement in your css and set the dimensions as per your need. If i am lagging some where then let me know.

Comment: Dear if my answer is correct then you can accept it. thats how stack overflow works. cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's empty, your `<div>` has 0 `height`.

You should set a height in CSS.

Comment: _Or_, put the background on the `body` element.

Comment: @powerbuoy: That would still need a height.

Comment: Oh absolutely, but if he's publishing a website without content in `body` I would reconsider publishing it at all.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is in your css dimension of `id="top_background"` is not set. **By default div contains it width 100% because div is block level element.**

In your case you are repeating background image so we have to set the height of the div to see the background image.

Its up to you how much width and height you want to set.

**For example:** You want to repeat your background image upto `600px` and `200px.` For that see below css

```
#top_background 
{ 
    background: url(images/header.png) repeat-x; 
    width:600px;
    height:200px
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I needed to set a height, I thought it would default to something that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined height into your **#top_background** thats why image is not repeating.

so whenever you repeat the image on y-axis or x-axis check the width height and set it according to your requirement.

now you can just add the mentioned below css and can set the width according to your requirement.

```
#top_background 
{ 
    background: url(images/header.png) repeat-x; 
    height:200px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this     background-repeat:repeat-x;